# Easiest way to share a music track on Facebook

Tags: facebook, music

I have some MP3 music tracks (written, performed, and recorded by me and some friends a few years ago, so no copyright issues) that I'd like to post onto facebook and share with my friends (and ideally not too easy for the web in general to get at them).

What is the easiest way to do this? I know with pictures and videos, you can just upload them to your account and share to friends/groups but I don't think I've seen a similar feature for music?

Answer (score 2):

I use [box.net](http://box.net/) for this. You can publish a link to a file on the site in Facebook, and it's free unless you have a *lot* of stuff to share.

Answer (score 2):

Another case solved by [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/). After installed, drag the file to the Public folder in your Dropbox and right click Copy Public Link. Then you can post the link as a status or send them in IM messages.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have some web space from your ISP it might be easiest to upload them there and link to them on your profile.

If you create a sub folder and (if possible) set the rights on it so no one can list the contents then it will be harder (but not impossible) to get to them without the direct link.

Comment: Thanks, I realise that with all these things it's just a case of making it harder for people to share your stuff with the world, you're never going to defeat someone determined.

Comment: @GAThrawn - I added the caveats so I wouldn't get sarky comments about the files being discoverable by someone determined, not to imply you were after an impossible requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload it to Soundcloud and post the link in your Facebook. It will add a preview so that the user doesn't have to open a new tab to listen to your song.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A friend has just pointed me to this thread on Facebook [how do I Upload WAV format audio files ?](http://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=6164314419&topic=4143) The gist of which is to upload your files to an external hosting service and then link to them, or upload your files to an external hosting service and then use a Facebook app to make it slightly easier to link to them.